# easyadmin bundle sort custom generated columns on sortable field

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony4, easyadmin

Have EasyAdmin bundle config like this, and added list fields, and some of them added marked as sortable, some not. And cant find nowhere how to make sortable field:
1) which is relation field from another entity. I.e. `OtherEntityName.columnName`;
2) which is custom generated field from i.e. 2 fields (here is `fullname` which is made from `firstname` and `lastname` fields from the `EntityName` entity

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        EntityName:
            class: App\Entity\EntityName
            label: EntityName
            list:
                fields:
                    - {property: id, sortable: true}
                    - {property: createdAt, sortable: true}
                    - {property: fullName, sortable: true}
                    - {property: OtherEntityName.columnName, sortable: true}
```

cant find how to make it sortable, but not sorted by default. Need to make it admin action to sort, not by default like in this example:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        EntityName:
            class: App\Entity\EntityName
            label: EntityName
            list:
                fields:
                    - {property: id, sortable: true}
                    - {property: createdAt, sortable: true}
                    - {property: fullName, sortable: true}
                    - {property: OtherEntityName.columnName, sortable: true}
                sort: ['createdAt', 'ASC']
```